# Dockerfiles sharing the same instructions but built from a different image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What would be the best practice when I need to create multiple docker images that share the same instructions EXCEPT the FROM image?

For example, I want to build 3 different images - a Java stack, a Python stack, and a Rust stack.  So I have 3 Dockerfile's each referencing a different FROM image. Then, in each of these Dockerfile, I have a long list of instructions that are exactly the same.  I would rather not duplicate the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing image name as  arguments if only image name is changing

Dockerfile:

```
ARG img
FROM $img
RUN echo “Building $img”
```

Then run build command on terminal:

```
sudo docker build . --build-arg img=busybox
```